# Problem cause with libxml2 ( i can not access in my parameter ... wifi, bluetooth ...)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

i do a locate libxml2.so.2 and i see this version of libxml

```
/snap/atom/282/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/atom/282/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.10
/snap/code/82/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.10
/snap/snap-store/547/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/snap-store/547/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4
/snap/snap-store/558/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/snap/snap-store/558/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.10
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.8.0
```

when i try to execute

```
gnome-control-center
```

i get this error

```
  gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgoa-backend-1.0.so.1)
    gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
```

who can i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the same problem experienced [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496425/problem-cause-with-libxml2-after-upgrade-from-12-04-to-14-04),
try to move your libxml files from /usr/local/lib/ to somewhere else. Try this

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libxml2* ~
```

Comment: Nice it's worked.